# Convergence of $S_n(a) = \sum_{an < k \leqslant (a+1)n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn-an^2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ et $n \in\mathbb{N}$,

Denote the following sequence,
$$\displaystyle S_n(a) = \sum_{an < k \leqslant (a+1)n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn-an^2}}$$

> For which values ​​of $a$ the sequence $(S_n(a))$ converges?

With an [Integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) we can prove that $$\sum_{an+1 < k \leq an+n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn-an^2}} \to 2$$

However, I don't see how can I continue ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to say $k$ is an integer. My apology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $k$ shall be an integer, otherwise it would be unclear which set it should traverse.

With $j = k - \lfloor an\rfloor$, we have

$$S_n(a) = \sum_{an < k \leqslant (a+1)n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn-an^2}} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\lfloor an\rfloor + j)n - an^2}} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{(j-(an-\lfloor an\rfloor))n}}.$$

Let us write $\rho_n(a) = an - \lfloor an\rfloor$. By definition, we have $0 \leqslant \rho_n(a) < 1$.

For the sum without the first term, we have the easy estimates

$$\sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{jn}} \leqslant \tilde{S}_n(a) := \sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{(j-\rho_n(a))n}} < \sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{(j-1)n}}$$

where both outer terms tend to $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = 2$.

So the convergence of $S_n(a)$ is entirely determined by the behaviour of the first term

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\rho_n(a))n}}.$$

If there is a $c > 0$ such that $1-\rho_n(a) \geqslant c$ for all $n$, then the first term is at most $\frac{1}{\sqrt{cn}}$ and tends to $0$, whence in that case $S_n(a) \to 2$. For rational $a$ such a $c > 0$ exists, so $S_n(a)$ converges (to $2$) for all rational $a$.

But for irrational $a$, if we denote the convergents of the continued fraction of $a$ by $\frac{p_m}{q_m}$, we have

$$\left\lvert a - \frac{p_m}{q_m}\right\rvert < \frac{1}{q_m^2}.$$

The convergents with odd indices are all $> a$, thus

$$0 < \frac{p_{2m+1}}{q_{2m+1}} - a < \frac{1}{q_{2m+1}^2} \iff 0 < p_{2m+1} - q_{2m+1}a < \frac{1}{q_{2m+1}},$$

and we see that $\lfloor q_{2m+1} a\rfloor = p_{2m+1}-1$ and

$$1 - \rho_{q_{2m+1}}(a) = 1+\lfloor q_{2m+1}a\rfloor - q_{2m+1}a = p_{2m+1}- q_{2m+1}a,$$

and so

$$0 < (1-\rho_{q_{2m+1}}(a))q_{2m+1} < 1,$$

which means that the first term in $S_n(a)$ is greater than $1$ infinitely often. But for the convergents with even indices, we have

$$0 < \rho_{q_{2m}}(a) = q_{2m}a - p_{2m} < \frac{1}{q_{2m}},$$

and thus $1-\rho_n(a) > \frac{1}{2}$ for infinitely many $n$, so for irrational $a$, we have

$$2 = \liminf_{n\to\infty} S_n(a) < 3 \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} S_n(a).$$

Result:

$S_n(a)$ converges if and only if $a \in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Very very nice! I am confused that not seeing @Lucian assumed that $k$ is a real. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$k=an+j$, with $j\in\overline{1\ldots n}=>S_n(a)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac1{\sqrt{jn}}=\dfrac1n\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac1{\sqrt{\dfrac jn}}$ , which tends to $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$ as *n* tends to infinity, whose value is $2$. See [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) for more details.

Comment: Why not ? *a* and *k* may be real, but *n* and *j* are always positive integers.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the substitution, nor does $S(\sqrt2)$ diverge.

Comment: I meant that your observation is simply incorrect. Obviously, $1<\sqrt2<2$, so, by the squeeze theorem, $S(\sqrt2)$ lies in between $S(1)$ and $S(2)$. Since the latter two are convergent, then so is the former.

Comment: No, $S(a)$ doesn't "obviously" depend on *a*, for the same reason that a (constant) function does not "obviously" or necessarily depend on its argument. Just write out the first few terms of the sum, and see it for yourself. As for the squeezing part, since $1<\sqrt2<2$ it is quite trivial to show that $S(\sqrt2)$ lies in between $S(1)$ and $S(2)$.

Comment: Lucian, Nico has right, you cannot make the substitution $k=an+j$ because we don't know if $an$ is rational.

Comment: @Julien: The only thing that by definition has to be natural is the number of iterations. Obviously, we can't have a fractional or negative number of iterations. We have $n-1$ iterations, with *k* starting at a certain value, $an+1$, and then, at each step, being incremented with $1$, $n-1$ times, until, at the $n-1$-th step, its value is $(a+1)n$. (If non-natural iterators really confuse you *that* much, then next time just don't use them). You seem to confuse the **iterator** with the **number of iterations**: but they are two completely *different* things.

Comment: @Lucian Though it is not _explicitly_ said anywhere, I'm rather convinced that $k$ shall be an integer. Thus $k$ would take the values $\lfloor an\rfloor + 1\, \lfloor an\rfloor + 2,\dotsc, \lfloor an\rfloor + n$. It would be unusual to use $k$ for it otherwise.

Comment: @Lucian As Daniel Fischer, I thought $k$ was 'implicitly' an integer.

Comment: @Julien: It is not impossible, but, as I wrote in a comment to a question now deleted, both Mapple and Mathematica, for instance, accept $\sum$ expressions where the iterator is *not* necessarily natural. E.g., $\displaystyle\sum_{k=\pi}^{\pi+7}1=8$, so, in my opinion, the question is ambiguously phrased. Either way, now the question has an answer for each of its two possible interpretations.

Comment: @Lucian I see your point, so I guess you're right, the question was not clear enough :)